# Laravel 6 can't show names of items from another table

Tags: php, laravel

So when I want to create a new cake, I need to have the category names to show up in a dropdown. 
I made a `hasMany` relationship between `Category.php` and `Cake.php`.

At the moment, I can only get the `category_id` in the value of an option but not the name of the category.

**Category.php**: Where I declared the relationship.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];


    public function cake()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cake::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

**CreateCakesTable.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCakesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->decimal('price');
            $table->integer('size');
            $table->boolean('published')->default(false);
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cakes');
    }
}
```

**CreateCategoriesTable.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category_id" @error('category_id') class="text-danger" @enderror>Categorie</label>
    <select class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror" name="category_id" id="category_id">
        <option disabled selected value> -- Selecteer een categorie -- </option>
        @foreach ($cake as $cake)
        <option value="{{ $cake->category->id ?? '' }}">{{ $cake->category->name ?? 'Geen categorie'}}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>
    @error('category_id')
    <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: cake->category->name doesn't return anuthing is that right ?

Comment: Correct, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Please post the category migration. Also, what does var_dump($cake->category) returns ?

Comment: When I put in the var_dump, I get: Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Did you define the inverse of the relatonship on the cake model ?

Comment: No I didn't. I did it now and the names show up! But I get duplicate names.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not define the relationship on the Cake model. That's why you get an error no nothing at all.

I would modify the model and the migration class like below. (I assume a cake could only belongs to one category)

**Cake model**

```
class Cake extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

}
```

**Cakes Migration**

```
class CreateCakesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->decimal('price');
            $table->integer('size');
            $table->boolean('published')->default(false);
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

After you edited the migration file run

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

**Warning**: Keep in mind that it will delete all data.

Comment: When I added your code, I got this error when migrating: PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `programmeren`.`cakes` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

Comment: I've reset the database and run the line but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Ismail change bigIncrements the by increments. It should work.

Comment: @Ismail by timestamped filename, which migration is running first? categories should be first in this case

Comment: @Ismail delete your cakes migration file if you dont understand what lagbox is saying then create a new one.

Comment: @TanvirAhmed I've already tried that too. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First thing if you have `hasMany` relation you should name it as plural name in your case `cake` have to be `cakes` and the wrong in your statement I think it because array name `$cake` is the same as it's single item `$cake` in you ex:

```
@foreach ($cake as $cake)
```

Make it like this

```
@foreach ($cakes as $cake)
```

and change it from your controller where you have passed it to view.

Answer (score 0):

In **category.php**, change:

`return $this->hasMany(Cake::class, 'category_id', 'id');`

To:

`return $this->hasMany('App\Cake', 'category_id', 'id');`

The other model should return:

`return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');`.

This will define the relationships correctly. If you visit the [Laravel Eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), you'll see that it uses the `App\Example` notation instead of `Example::class`. It's less confusing this way and less prone to errors.

Also make sure that your `@foreach` loop is correct. Send the variable `$cakes` to the view, having the foreach loop look like this: `@foreach($cakes as $cake)`.

Correct me if I'm wrong.